# Customizing the lables of a legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following plot:

[image]

I would like to show a lable in the legend for those green hexabins with the label `<25%`. I generated the plot using the following script:

```
BR = percent(0.25*0:4)
min_max_trans = trans_new("min_max",function(i)i/(max(i)-min(i)),inverse=identity)
df <- read.csv("/home/nasser/Desktop/Trash/prices_volume.csv")
dt_long <- gather(df, key, value, -Prices)
gp <- ggplot(dt_long, aes(Prices, value)) + geom_hex(bins = 13) + 
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = 'free_y', ncol = 3) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = brewer.pal(3,"Dark2"), trans=min_max_trans,labels=percent(0.25*0:4), guide = guide_legend()) +
  theme(text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 18), axis.text.x=element_text(angle=40, hjust=1)) + labs(fill = "Count") +
  geom_smooth(method="lm") + theme(panel.spacing = unit(1.5, "lines"), legend.position="top", legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "cm"))
```

and the following data:

```
structure(list(Volume_2017 = c(0.824711312741894, 0.915711295232019, 
0.996337891880306, 0.963670127455352, 0.877393091433848, 0.830821047805372, 
0.841660156074548, 0.900994066121647, 0.848267466391695, 0.814532201404833, 
0.657354363193108, 1, 0.965912077820191, 0.864717997046078, 0.81465775852348, 
0.474185130108644, 0.904874375606611, 0.900375440947856, 0.931524575400957, 
0.922498316364837, 0.908707557672312, 0.644017135881595, 0.941048042796854, 
0.679619775362861, 0.728851736717989, 0.951794394193276, 0.796654959892513, 
0.846133250446692, 0.960234814075962, 0.941566987353403, 0.875415843792012, 
0.866463123575804, 0.919860154070673, 0.922602016381034, 0.851235022502933, 
0.880933734139818, 0.815131201700984, 0.790028974964121, 0.632573532833423, 
0.762689335286665, 0.714591141035648, 0.651789775666478, 0.828379610829269, 
0.740719704236935, 0.869931342831344, 0.983667238077781, 0.835074053639401, 
0.715729898431409, 0.724455744188118, 0.918199301649904, 0.908459831173911, 
0.882387872449206, 0.937238883600678, 0.831501627694624, 0.784379440652519, 
0.881666566098315, 0.880387575097157, 0.870096127149947, 0.915636473765141, 
1, 0.879518996298533, 0.88677995787238, 0.917968587447233, 0.856094497305008, 
0.856071857504223, 0.868498070397065, 0.821042259307134, 0.864757897587371, 
0.943004421145016, 0.940702096565525, 0.991117852002588, 0.879283726703994, 
0.859919469424183, 0.852532618779132, 0.747334497789751, 0.848401195479997, 
0.876409107849085, 0.76116663044178, 0.871950913227784, 0.854316604016639, 
0.932410593456246, 0.925842502098117, 0.902244197575864, 0.660246803203674, 
0.809948270674638, 0.842325502302075, 0.861698869472603, 0.988206079215344, 
0.879282230577452, 0.69076686337143, 0.851929355778359, 1, 0.754326659670962, 
0.75198786220609, 0.853495027434347, 0.905276184897953, 0.923154215581216, 
0.850512154243651, 0.865664458393566, 0.835191072475417, 0.937888752591144, 
0.814879583933719, 0.809106725020935, 0.74457089072944, 0.915032669133091, 
0.854029794087723, 0.854693511570169, 0.727463768584832, 0.821148156989907, 
0.888023290720753, 0.862871742611654, 0.903752462618845, 0.837138787957664, 
0.840228254605193, 0.877430798404977, 0.841427591425816, 0.893141793718152, 
0.869789455245567, 0.838968314295522, 0.857253018373696, 0.882912189801298, 
0.855328430658243, 0.893479230672201, 0.393303123065151, 0.736136413458874, 
0.845182111801668, 0.872285684194234, 0.774814902651245, 0.779707186810304, 
0.741629568641077, 0.801935978324457, 0.878189027935294, 0.847342567916366, 
0.834319648636115, 0.885205380235904, 0.791476850860223, 0.769043544804505, 
0.915927778310761, 0.855565630338174, 0.935734410351538, 0.893688354716787, 
0.795357373359823, 0.954636151934739, 0.861022706614273, 0.917176320042935, 
0.852442316883921, 0.967143241857076, 0.929819691364446, 0.883152256576581, 
0.944127849493313, 0.777801378486704, 0.915929754831932, 0.912976866848287, 
0.789424683178141, 0.947420552368658, 0.909919126845949, 0.907242481858967, 
0.876639804485154, 0.865101309691293, 0.777145847648749, 0.909733251974376, 
0.828157301241112, 0.883754583307844, 0.872693694631855, 0.901490595561084, 
0.766258873319923, 0.943873960757459, 0.822698294316994, 0.828285848516905, 
0.89056708446401, 0.796018788830221, 0.927132863792514, 1, 0.997458634985182, 
0.274958061838929, 0.787487767125462, 0.951188541379124, 0.833423095377985, 
0.909690837980405, 0.811139869865459, 0.804185291725837, 0.931713647000955, 
0.978156335364873, 0.711314236933727, 0.994136895809263, 0.887308093062124, 
0.86469273603586, 0.862108357710104, 0.884542642634386, 0.855778931380096, 
0.928164484701284, 0.939355667437049, 0.933020576836232, 0.949322464862746, 
0.896689516914374, 0.849642781758329, 0.846534325707848, 0.835686104271818, 
0.825092473477198, 0.898277797514682, 0.819751113761411, 0.874665407892681, 
0.981908574421876, 0.863049339141498, 0.987043233834958, 0.822098191447755, 
0.832288690195035, 0.920749911488653, 0.871766101237158, 0.891889009416148, 
0.912196800595273, 0.857699460645669, 0.807166757286395, 0.753516836131138, 
0.751013460355367, 0.81912255349386, 0.77254196112121, 0.961693437389675, 
0.993942653203055, 0.996817791181849, 0.996864572337506, 0.948778843831823, 
0.660754705392749, 0.589569204238877, 0.973357829777803, 0.989457097777535, 
0.785271682592647, 0.873566212440884, 0.848111974094123, 0.836181475132432, 
0.924732704091675, 0.86223595573823, 0.845716848707734, 0.750425285112076, 
0.881776963437419, 0.894303366672644, 0.87746717148318, 0.853253724513418, 
0.866525586984792, 0.854049606734896, 0.941885398319796, 0.899204727254876, 
0.920600218781275, 0.88963691844331, 0.796813460570667, 0.529871229804895, 
0.789259638590895, 0.757026228568754, 0.905549930610653, 0.881933893499432, 
0.829035443153687, 0.846093489021016, 0.726439089973248, 0.762053957261507, 
0.756904281157693, 0.781929083113519, 0.819047063180147, 0.813233115666515, 
0.804506879395258, 0.812492815203243, 0.877141935475535, 0.866864601569792, 
0.873985040742266, 0.865553058451435, 0.925732755540251, 0.835842862271606, 
0.880459080140377, 0.849510421572219, 0.873816567090615, 0.835842872791468, 
0.886723642629289, 0.815334143941545, 0.854357160780713, 0.782440348333119, 
0.837650591207202, 0.834500136366311, 0.781911859095871, 0.97477402827307, 
0.888958934093002, 0.467627194258831, 0.878145437996109, 0.959660634076345, 
0.914679800652855, 0.917836552037272, 0.912575359627271, 0.902128364606873, 
0.864079525710874, 0.792135141054365, 0.805384420779762, 0.873839469430045, 
0.11038987336682, 0.766299490250383, 0.649424683489033, 0.898850780452908, 
0.805737327876253, 0.726946109393128, 0.79441693983753, 0.86438237983567, 
0.891279513528587, 0.985620018209899, 0.852084200922344, 0.794581863731762, 
0.85773708593442, 0.893397559134288, 0.877017887586094, 0.802391756781888, 
0.799291217175045, 0.691138577887402, 0.89661629629492, 0.873845815527948, 
0.946302359969951, 0.939679963110706, 0.87036059371433, 0.86324348854792, 
0.88792353694477, 0.903791303085598, 0.870695393272322, 0.787912019679365, 
0.802933421708709, 0.850819417463593, 0.831880524327038, 0.876675034694797, 
0.846697407949702, 0.87508972141694, 0.922790723051332, 0.886555949395015, 
0.806451903919243, 0.887173491441452, 0.857694325254468, 0.870247111805308
), Volume_2018 = c(0.275820192307692, 0.893539175257732, 0.974596153846154, 
0.974798695136418, 0.137144791666667, 0.016583783783784, 0.812040740740741, 
0.154936625514403, 0.028965517241379, 0.013487301587302, 0.103206944444444, 
1, 0.980094190476191, 0.062264102564103, 0.016136815920398, 0.278742577030812, 
0.076207407407407, 0.149742105263158, 0.097817182130584, 0.025682666666667, 
0.024355555555556, 0.446663928234183, 0.658380116959064, 0.237148489751888, 
0.558829653679654, 0.813615555555556, 0.307517615176152, 0.111426666666667, 
0.798025225225225, 0.712947975077882, 0.074387654320988, 0.113767441860465, 
0.356051851851852, 0.196755026455026, 0.587235697399527, 0.03912030075188, 
0.339950959860384, 0.245566666666667, 0.549292918192918, 0.372458192090396, 
0.854923754789272, 0.642270677506775, 0.51989387755102, 0.404667619047619, 
0.122972151898734, 0.96574367816092, 0.008761458333333, 0.016220634920635, 
0.016601666666667, 0.528573333333333, 0.593175396825397, 0.947735319148936, 
0.066970555555556, 0.068362365591398, 0.103485897435897, 0.084468, 
0.094783333333333, 0.028014102564103, 0.045388596491228, 1, 0.380967862481315, 
0.031569791666667, 0.263062962962963, 0.132205555555556, 0.134368, 
0.341482051282051, 0.02115, 0.081933636363636, 0.05226894977169, 
0.031851207729469, 0.934472864321608, 0.116339043209877, 0.526843493761141, 
0.092008547008547, 0.084494636015326, 0.237788461538462, 0.048304242424242, 
0.05046, 0.015590476190476, 0.016752083333333, 0.12977039800995, 
0.052481531531532, 0.288691025641026, 0.680733714285714, 0.010292156862745, 
0.575935869565217, 0.300576666666667, 0.927562962962963, 0.579338095238095, 
0.032643859649123, 0.627024074074074, 1, 0.807731541218638, 0.734259420289855, 
0.46833843537415, 0.3882335839599, 0.031087562189055, 0.205581220657277, 
0.875329801324503, 0.022569230769231, 0.944547826086957, 0.002027631578947, 
0.083654742547426, 0.469651300236407, 0.076869387755102, 0.043854022988506, 
0.01643768115942, 0.012672222222222, 0.143735, 0.094359047619048, 
0.159841739130435, 0.539871014492754, 0.304207359307359, 0.273317316017316, 
0.186431666666667, 0.299729501915709, 0.36857662835249, 0.176481666666667, 
0.263249703440095, 0.331124130190797, 0.295198293963255, 0.295204593175853, 
0.122190625, 0.299185, 0.015382142857143, 0.194842929292929, 
0.011489644012945, 0.571210909090909, 0.137965040650407, 0.366414102564103, 
0.137043478260869, 0.140039024390244, 0.020124637681159, 0.163898587570621, 
0.765545045045045, 0.101985858585859, 0.048680952380952, 0.032328358208955, 
0.137294202898551, 0.880911764705882, 0.108063768115942, 0.464475063613232, 
0.132850170068027, 0.101281349206349, 0.539273611111111, 0.116971428571429, 
0.525810144927536, 0.951572857142857, 0.288561904761905, 0.520912454212454, 
0.025363636363636, 0.025966666666667, 0.038377380952381, 0.094717204301075, 
0.0535016, 0.359178070175439, 0.044183333333333, 0.161834615384615, 
0.113179591836735, 0.295052777777778, 0.058001190476191, 0.00785, 
0.041603703703704, 0.013383660130719, 0.049865277777778, 0.155597530864198, 
0.59126862745098, 0.012616049382716, 0.153414893617021, 0.071856910569106, 
0.021824242424242, 0.055051558752998, 1, 0.978361481481481, 0.195139122807018, 
0.298541176470588, 0.849583660130719, 0.018665079365079, 0.285181981981982, 
0.370052032520325, 0.233163541666667, 0.590147008547009, 0.067020512820513, 
0.935034920634921, 0.167670833333333, 0.228947278911565, 0.168984523809524, 
0.55066103500761, 0.014602996254682, 0.125413836477987, 0.089512985274431, 
0.06566091954023, 0.153232330827068, 0.015496632996633, 0.29668574879227, 
0.057335416666667, 0.225419351230425, 0.044399161425577, 0.403421666666667, 
0.273547014925373, 0.834656687898089, 0.2231525, 0.968632850241546, 
0.415563131313131, 0.134697368421053, 0.091715497076023, 0.019502564102564, 
0.027055769230769, 0.092525474254743, 0.376268972746331, 0.060901075268817, 
0.36183115942029, 0.258645121951219, 0.078417741935484, 0.265216384180791, 
0.829857333333333, 0.90393947368421, 0.976516747181965, 0.987171812080537, 
0.041933838383838, 0.14469756097561, 0.0018, 0.816031720430108, 
0.976385714285715, 0.403433502538071, 0.27584219858156, 0.588626262626263, 
0.241824509803922, 0.019090085470086, 0.040233673469388, 0.051267619047619, 
0.283458796296296, 0.032725714285714, 0.017676315789474, 0.035877777777778, 
0.29368862745098, 0.027642857142857, 0.659925227963526, 0.118011754385965, 
0.112990944123314, 0.072302380952381, 0.044925683060109, 0.167938518518518, 
0.096359677419355, 0.293318666666667, 0.237096825396825, 0.099456197352587, 
0.559579914529915, 0.241491039426523, 0.031533333333333, 0.443614351851852, 
0.471591666666667, 0.475333755274262, 0.019831111111111, 0.258174433656958, 
0.263783980099503, 0.106017567567568, 0.22167940552017, 0.342963713080169, 
0.143389308176101, 0.113013756613757, 0.433080654761905, 0.203992520325203, 
0.320586135693215, 0.36911, 0.354455263157895, 0.261255472636816, 
0.287155813953488, 0.247658333333333, 0.304218905472637, 0.061283333333333, 
0.915321072796935, 0.210064705882353, 0.01570625, 0.474887234042553, 
0.055848198198198, 0.500458187134503, 0.59689121756487, 0.027167632850242, 
0.336858181818182, 0.029661111111111, 0.010729166666667, 0.056489189189189, 
0.006384444444444, 0.022380952380952, 0.0348, 0.484978240740741, 
0.060780229885058, 0.034403801169591, 0.024401075268817, 0.445942592592593, 
0.928834981684982, 0.82974703196347, 0.692745333333333, 0.085552604166667, 
0.241129927007299, 0.736533333333333, 0.028177380952381, 0.008393939393939, 
0.935500952380952, 0.040153086419753, 0.05486358974359, 0.067377777777778, 
0.079684567901235, 0.566339694656489, 0.076475338753388, 0.510466562173459, 
0.035443333333333, 0.309928947368421, 0.078731800766284, 0.145661788617886, 
0.105218576388889, 0.272696153846154, 0.076016129032258, 0.386050312109863, 
0.157926585695007, 0.038458620689655, 0.133850383141762, 0.279600574712644, 
0.186369166666667, 0.275820192307692, 0.893539175257732, 0.974596153846154, 
0.974798695136418, 0.137144791666667, 0.016583783783784, 0.812040740740741, 
0.154936625514403, 0.028965517241379, 0.013487301587302), Volume_2019 = c(0.002414102564097, 
0.001174398625467, 0.0010256410256, 0.001051838671393, 0.002878125, 
0.004077477477493, 0.00177037037037, 0.003053909465023, 0.00206551724138, 
0.002257142857167, 0.002033333333333, 0.001, 0.001072380952367, 
0.0029717948718, 0.002232587064677, 0.00201036414567, 0.0021, 
0.00292771929824, 0.003005841924393, 0.008772666666667, 0.002482539682533, 
0.0016028328612, 0.001884795321637, 0.001899568500543, 0.001675757575777, 
0.0012, 0.002775880758787, 0.002668333333327, 0.00151171171169, 
0.001388785046723, 0.00607530864197, 0.00415348837209, 0.002834814814827, 
0.008986243386227, 0.0020964539007, 0.005417543859647, 0.00207905759162, 
0.002877168949767, 0.001929792429827, 0.003026553672313, 0.00150344827588, 
0.001880108401087, 0.001844047619057, 0.002190952380963, 0.00348396624472, 
0.0010344827586, 0.006220833333333, 0.00308730158726, 0.002998333333333, 
0.00227777777778, 0.002014484126987, 0.00126765957446, 0.003718888888883, 
0.005132616487453, 0.002628205128203, 0.004248, 0.007026293103447, 
0.002628205128207, 0.003443421052633, 0.001, 0.002645739910313, 
0.008983333333333, 0.0017777777778, 0.002870370370367, 0.003363333333333, 
0.00210256410256, 0.003542857142857, 0.002534848484847, 0.00231506849313, 
0.002258454106293, 0.001163484087093, 0.005761111111113, 0.00211039809863, 
0.002683760683757, 0.016383908045983, 0.002228205128207, 0.00215212121213, 
0.004805, 0.010981904761907, 0.00828875, 0.00274427860695, 0.002558108108107, 
0.002019444444443, 0.0015914285714, 0.004362745098053, 0.002043840579703, 
0.002366666666667, 0.001103703703693, 0.001742857142873, 0.004219298245603, 
0.00166712962963, 0.001, 0.0013430107527, 0.0015434782609, 0.002538775510207, 
0.003559899749367, 0.0025592039801, 0.00343615023474, 0.001239955849933, 
0.002176923076903, 0.001110144927567, 0.00341403508773, 0.003459349593493, 
0.002460283687937, 0.00319863945578, 0.00226666666666, 0.018426086956527, 
0.003018888888873, 0.002331666666667, 0.003414285714283, 0.002526956521737, 
0.00519710144927, 0.002732034632027, 0.002861904761897, 0.003106666666673, 
0.002896934865907, 0.00257969348659, 0.003066111111117, 0.00349881376038, 
0.00244814814815, 0.00230262467191, 0.002416272965877, 0.00248125, 
0.001801666666667, 0.007639880952377, 0.002253030303033, 0.009329126213587, 
0.00166909090911, 0.00293821138211, 0.004464102564097, 0.002315942029033, 
0.003039024390237, 0.015501449275363, 0.008321468926553, 0.009915315315317, 
0.004964646464643, 0.00526488095237, 0.004199004975113, 0.00949130434782, 
0.001162745098033, 0.00265942028985, 0.002461323155213, 0.013436054421777, 
0.003893253968247, 0.001716666666667, 0.00195595238097, 0.0019130434783, 
0.001076190476233, 0.001866269841277, 0.003128937728933, 0.0021, 
0.00230238095237, 0.00248333333332, 0.00281397849465, 0.002320533333333, 
0.002299122807017, 0.002, 0.00275, 0.002816326530617, 0.002254166666667, 
0.00369761904762, 0.00381875, 0.003125925925927, 0.005600000000007, 
0.00369861111111, 0.002507407407373, 0.0014117647059, 0.003214814814817, 
0.002590070921973, 0.00297479674797, 0.01804242424242, 0.00463980815348, 
0.001, 0.0010222222222, 0.001853947368427, 0.0017058823529, 0.0011568627451, 
0.003668253968263, 0.00215675675675, 0.001922222222237, 0.002383333333333, 
0.00296495726495, 0.04700512820514, 0.001080952380933, 0.007685648148143, 
0.0026112244898, 0.014720238095237, 0.00248949771689, 0.00493520599251, 
0.00640553459119, 0.004878313253013, 0.00365545977011, 0.004275689223057, 
0.01131245791246, 0.003004106280193, 0.00678472222223, 0.005784004474273, 
0.004531446540867, 0.001835, 0.00332611940299, 0.001566454352443, 
0.01443125, 0.001049275362333, 0.007142424242427, 0.0240552631579, 
0.007115204678353, 0.003953846153853, 0.00365705128204, 0.005986720867213, 
0.002818448637317, 0.00557311827956, 0.00247934782609, 0.002582926829263, 
0.003732258064523, 0.00645706214689, 0.004855999999993, 0.001249122807027, 
0.0010241545894, 0.00103154362418, 0.013604545454543, 0.005505691056917, 
0.002934444444437, 0.002545340501793, 0.0010238095238, 0.00221370558375, 
0.00335000000001, 0.001788552188527, 0.00236274509804, 0.013679487179487, 
0.005909523809527, 0.003596190476187, 0.002676851851847, 0.00611942857143, 
0.005988596491227, 0.002, 0.002481045751637, 0.00392789115644, 
0.00167568389058, 0.002203684210527, 0.003684778420043, 0.0097238095238, 
0.00281311475409, 0.003364074074077, 0.002609677419357, 0.002558, 
0.002856746031737, 0.00735330926595, 0.001780128205137, 0.00261075268818, 
0.002848717948717, 0.00189058641975, 0.001945555555547, 0.001983966244727, 
0.005273333333327, 0.004203883495147, 0.003079104477617, 0.003092342342337, 
0.003043312101907, 0.00304556962024, 0.003135220125783, 0.004403703703707, 
0.002158333333327, 0.004803902439023, 0.00234247787612, 0.0019919047619, 
0.001954385964913, 0.003713432835827, 0.002959173126613, 0.00378965517242, 
0.00259552238807, 0.002186111111113, 0.001156704980857, 0.002354901960793, 
0.01525625, 0.0015957446809, 0.00489594594594, 0.001830409356733, 
0.00169753825682, 0.00253671497585, 0.01430363636364, 0.0025, 
0.016829166666667, 0.002627027027023, 0.002300000000033, 0.0022857142857, 
0.002, 0.001732870370397, 0.002788850574713, 0.00302105263158, 
0.008280645161293, 0.002154938271587, 0.003345421245423, 0.001345662100463, 
0.001486666666667, 0.00210078125, 0.002824574209243, 0.001466666666667, 
0.002, 0.002, 0.001147619047633, 0.00367654320988, 0.00385538461539, 
0.003284541062797, 0.00693765432099, 0.001989058524173, 0.004204607046073, 
0.002009299895507, 0.004667777777773, 0.00320292397661, 0.003397318007663, 
0.00231788617884, 0.005576388888893, 0.001764102564133, 0.002895698924767, 
0.001935205992517, 0.002502699055333, 0.002919540229867, 0.00350996168583, 
0.003030459770113, 0.002411666666667, 0.002414102564097, 0.001174398625467, 
0.0010256410256, 0.001051838671393, 0.002878125, 0.004077477477493, 
0.00177037037037, 0.003053909465023, 0.00206551724138, 0.002257142857167
), Prices = c(0.521955128205128, 0, 0, 0.194543297746145, 0.46875, 
0.810810810810811, 0.296296296296296, 0.436213991769547, 0, 0.19047619047619, 
0.020833333333333, 0, 0, 0.630769230769231, 0.007462686567164, 
0, 0.703703703703704, 0.707368421052632, 0.597250859106529, 0.88, 
0.666666666666667, 0, 0.135233918128655, 0.035490830636462, 0.027056277056277, 
0.066666666666667, 0.296747967479674, 0.419444444444445, 0.162162162162162, 
0.091277258566978, 0.923456790123457, 0.582170542635659, 0.28962962962963, 
0.793121693121694, 0.79338061465721, 0.875187969924812, 0.035951134380454, 
0.11324200913242, 0.029304029304029, 0.381194511702986, 0.03448275862069, 
0.095447154471545, 0.161734693877551, 0.123095238095238, 0.707594936708861, 
0, 0.8125, 0.857142857142857, 0.9, 0.933333333333333, 0.79920634920635, 
0.008510638297872, 0.713333333333333, 0.621505376344086, 0.232905982905983, 
0.868, 0.851580459770115, 0.743589743589744, 0.744298245614035, 
0, 0.434379671150972, 0.797916666666667, 0.222222222222222, 0.612962962962963, 
0.591333333333333, 0.516666666666667, 0.538095238095238, 0.611515151515151, 
0.642465753424657, 0.710144927536232, 0.122445561139028, 0.658487654320988, 
0.255852644087938, 0.641025641025641, 0.347892720306513, 0.076923076923077, 
0.353939393939394, 0.978333333333333, 0.755238095238095, 0.863333333333333, 
0.675124378109453, 0.672972972972973, 0.534401709401709, 0.005714285714286, 
0.92156862745098, 0.526449275362319, 0.128333333333333, 0, 0.19047619047619, 
0.471929824561404, 0.159722222222222, 0, 0, 0, 0.446258503401361, 
0.442105263157895, 0.821890547263682, 0.628169014084507, 0, 0.230769230769231, 
0.191304347826087, 0.400438596491228, 0.834417344173442, 0.204491725768322, 
0.746598639455782, 0.211494252873563, 0.869565217391304, 0.52, 
0.113333333333333, 0.637142857142857, 0.699420289855073, 0.739130434782609, 
0.457575757575758, 0.461904761904762, 0.788888888888889, 0.503065134099617, 
0.499616858237548, 0.793888888888889, 0.709015421115065, 0.591358024691358, 
0.477690288713911, 0.456692913385827, 0.40625, 0, 0.767857142857143, 
0.796969696969697, 0.914886731391586, 0.102424242424242, 0.48780487804878, 
0.192307692307692, 0, 0.365853658536585, 0.634782608695652, 0.38502824858757, 
0.698648648648649, 0.604040404040404, 0.814880952380952, 0.533582089552239, 
0.869565217391304, 0, 0.715942028985507, 0.749872773536896, 0.864455782312925, 
0.625, 0.333333333333333, 0.464285714285714, 0.104347826086957, 
0.078095238095238, 0.011904761904762, 0.427472527472528, 0.090909090909091, 
0.607142857142857, 0.607142857142857, 0.064516129032258, 0.500266666666667, 
0.526315789473684, 0, 0.752564102564103, 0.691836734693877, 0.208333333333333, 
0.5, 0.85625, 0.666666666666667, 0.600653594771242, 0.5, 0.279012345679012, 
0.117647058823529, 0.518518518518518, 0.808510638297872, 0.536585365853659, 
0.909090909090909, 0.82589928057554, 0, 0, 0.031754385964912, 
0.511764705882353, 0.019607843137255, 0.693650793650794, 0.183783783783784, 
0.105962059620596, 0.022916666666667, 0.062313432835821, 0.288888888888889, 
0.306666666666667, 0, 0.680787037037037, 0.74421768707483, 0.642857142857143, 
0.828462709284627, 0.887265917602996, 0.713710691823899, 0.760776439089692, 
0.72816091954023, 0.648370927318296, 0.765656565656566, 0.315458937198068, 
0.548387096774194, 0.295833333333334, 0.714765100671141, 0.812159329140461, 
0.05, 0.713681592039801, 0.109766454352441, 0.75625, 0, 0.427777777777778, 
0.684210526315789, 0.796783625730994, 0.71025641025641, 0.882051282051282, 
0.849593495934959, 0.650104821802935, 0.903225806451613, 0.895652173913044, 
0.374390243902439, 0.531182795698925, 0.842937853107345, 0.08, 
0.030075187969925, 0, 0.013422818791946, 0.937878787878788, 0.780487804878049, 
0.556666666666667, 0.50663082437276, 0, 0.368527918781726, 0.743971631205674, 
0.218181818181818, 0.764705882352941, 0.901880341880342, 0.792857142857143, 
0.157142857142857, 0.198148148148148, 0.799047619047619, 0.894736842105263, 
0, 0.318562091503268, 0.408843537414966, 0.085815602836879, 0.14280701754386, 
0.804624277456647, 0.571428571428571, 0.86775956284153, 0.624074074074074, 
0.241397849462366, 0.42, 0.716269841269841, 0.692539109506618, 
0.398290598290598, 0.474193548387097, 0.538461538461538, 0.225925925925926, 
0.166666666666667, 0.156540084388186, 0.666666666666667, 0.824595469255664, 
0.683681592039801, 0.709459459459459, 0.677494692144374, 0.657383966244726, 
0.834591194968553, 0.794179894179895, 0.533630952380953, 0.64, 
0.620648967551622, 0.478929188255613, 0.301428571428571, 0.103070175438597, 
0.729353233830846, 0.438501291989664, 0.430747126436782, 0.766862745098039, 
0.432835820895522, 0.166666666666667, 0.322630385487528, 0.363525091799266, 
0.668965517241379, 0.326334951456311, 0.062745098039216, 0.625, 
0.042553191489362, 0.617567567567568, 0.069005847953216, 0.081836327345309, 
0.695652173913043, 0.981818181818182, 0.5, 0.5, 0.432432432432432, 
0.266666666666667, 0.285714285714286, 0, 0.402777777777778, 0.711954022988506, 
0.643421052631579, 0.541115434500648, 0.774193548387097, 0.18641975308642, 
0.822710622710623, 0, 0, 0.021875, 0.091484184914842, 0, 0.00253807106599, 
0, 0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0.737435897435898, 0.759420289855072, 
0.666666666666667, 0.295928753180662, 0.75420054200542, 0.039602925809822, 
0.666666666666667, 0.183333333333333, 0.745210727969349, 0.439837398373984, 
0.653645833333333, 0, 0.193548387096774, 0.228838951310861, 0.729554655870445, 
0.380459770114942, 0.323786209710322, 0.844061302681992, 0.952873563218391, 
0.3325)), .Names = c("Volume_2017", "Volume_2018", "Volume_2019", 
"Prices"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -330L))
```

How can I show a green box in the legend with the lable `<25%`?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the legend breaks with `scale_fill_gradientn(...breaks = c())`

Comment: I'm can't reproduce your trans=min_max_trans - but this works for me: scale_fill_gradientn(colors = brewer.pal(3,"Dark2"), labels=percent(0.25*0:4), breaks = c(1, 8, 16, 24, 32), guide = guide_legend()) +